# Javascript Chart.js plotting data based on drop-down list selection from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, charts

I've made a chart from data shown below, the data displays the number of rentals made at bike stations based on the specific hour, the whole idea is to make the chart respond based on what we choose from the drop-down list which allows to choose a specific hour. The drop down list contains a list of Hours: From 0 (meaning 12 am) to 23 (meaning 11 pm), now if the user chose for example 16, and the same hour would exist in the column "startHour" from rentalsStationsTotal, the chart would show only rentals for hour 16 (meaning 4 pm).

The question is, what would the best approach be in order to make this with charts.js, The function to update the chart is at the end of the code called "updateChart()" But when selecting something from the drop down list the chart doesn't change at all.

```
<div class="container" style="width: 640px; height: 400px;">
<h2>Chart</h2>
<div>
   <form id="myForm">
      <select id="selectNumber">
      <option>Choose an hour</option>
      </select>
   </form>
   <canvas id="canvas3"></canvas>
</div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.1.4/Chart.min.js"></script>

<script>
var userRentals = [{"Rentals": 12377, "StartHour": 0}, {"Rentals": 7047, "StartHour": 1}, {"Rentals": 4102, "StartHour": 2}, {"Rentals": 2681, "StartHour": 3}
var rentalsStationsTotal = [{"Rentals": 1, "Name": "Aleja Bielany", "StartHour": 0}, {"Rentals": 4, "Name": "Aleja Bielany", "StartHour": 1}, {"Rentals": 1, "Name": "Aleja Bielany", "StartHour": 3}]

var userRentalsHours = [];
var stationRentalsLabels = [];
var stationRentalsData = [];

for (var i = 0; i < userRentals.length; i++) {
userRentalsHours.push(userRentals[i].StartHour);  
}
for (var i = 0; i < rentalsStationsTotal.length; i++) {
stationRentalsLabels.push(rentalsStationsTotal[i].Name);  
}
for (var i = 0; i < rentalsStationsTotal.length; i++) {
stationRentalsData.push(rentalsStationsTotal[i].Rentals);  
}

var ctx3 = document.getElementById("canvas3").getContext("2d");

var canvas3 = new Chart(ctx3, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
        labels : stationRentalsLabels, 
        datasets : [
            {
                label: 'godziny wypożyczeń w stacjach',
                fillColor : "rgba(220,280,220,0.5)",
                strokeColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                backgroundColor: "rgba(153,255,51,0.4)",
                data : stationRentalsData
            }]
        }
    });

/* Select Hour from drop down list */

var select = document.getElementById("selectNumber"); 
var options = userRentalsHours; 

for(var i = 0; i < userRentalsHours.length; i++) {
var opt = userRentalsHours[i];
var el = document.createElement("option");
el.text = opt;
el.value = opt;
select.add(el);
}

var currentChart;
var stationRentalsHoursTemp = [];

function updateChart() {
if(currentChart){currentChart.destroy();}

var determineHour = $("#selectNumber").val();
for (var i = 0; i < stationRentalsHours.length; i++) {
if(determineHour == stationRentalsHours[i]){
stationRentalsHoursTemp.push(rentalsHoursInDays[i].Date);  
}
}
var params = canvas3[determineHour]
currentChart = new Chart(ctx3)[params.method](params.data, {});
}
$('#selectNumber').on('change', updateChart)
updateChart();
</script>
```